# How can I have taskbar at the bottom of the screen in Ubuntu 15?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, taskbar

I just installed Ubuntu 15 GNOME, and the taskbar is missing!

How can I place the taskbar at the bottom of my screen? Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

There *is* no "taskbar" in GNOME 3.

The GNOME 3 way to switch apps/open new ones is to hover/click your mouse on the "Activities" in the top-left corner.

If you want a (sort-of) taskbar, you may be interested in [tint2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tint2), or [Docky](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) or [Plank](http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Welcome_to_the_Docky_wiki) (beta). You can also use [Dash-to-Dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/), a GNOME extension.